# Can't CVE-2019-2215 on Android: "Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address"

Tags: android

I'm playing with Android and I'm trying to gain r/w access to the whole memory using CVE-2019-2215. Long story short, you UAF a `binder_thread` object and you can read from/write to kernel space.

The first step, getting `task_struct`, works as expected but overwriting `addr_limit` doesn't. The error `Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address` and the fact that other people on other devices can perform this makes me think there's something else behind that problem.

I get this kernel panic:

```
[  400.258967] Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address fffffffffffffffe
[  400.258997] pgd = ffffffe55194e000
[  400.259007] [fffffffffffffffe] *pgd=00000000d194f003, *pud=00000000d194f003, *pmd=0000000000000000
[  400.259146] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[  400.259152] Kernel BUG at ffffff80e9b9cbc4 [verbose debug info unavailable]
[  400.259159] Internal error: Oops - BUG: 96000005 [#1] PREEMPT SMP
[  400.259167] Modules linked in: wlan(O) exfat(O)
[  400.259203] CPU: 2 PID: 6877 Comm: cve-2019-2215 Tainted: G        W  O    4.4.78-perf+ #1
[  400.259210] Hardware name: Qualcomm Technologies, Inc. SDM 636 PM660 + PM660L MTP E7S (DT)
[  400.259217] task: ffffffe5f84d0d80 ti: ffffffe551910000 task.ti: fffffffffffffffe
[  400.259235] PC is at n_tty_write+0x168/0x3e8
[  400.259242] LR is at n_tty_write+0xa4/0x3e8
[  400.259248] pc : [<ffffff80e9b9cbc4>] lr : [<ffffff80e9b9cb00>] pstate: 60400145
[  400.259253] sp : ffffffe551913c70
[  400.259258] x29: ffffffe551913c70 x28: ffffffe551910000 
[  400.259268] x27: ffffffe51f344230 x26: ffffff80ea687000 
[  400.259278] x25: ffffffe5dcdda200 x24: ffffffe51f341c00 
[  400.259287] x23: ffffffe51f3440d8 x22: ffffff80e96eb000 
[  400.259297] x21: ffffffe51f341c00 x20: 0000000000000008 
[  400.259312] x19: ffffffe51f344000 x18: fca83dec72c82c59 
[  400.259325] x17: 00000070696c35c8 x16: ffffff80e97cd198 
[  400.259334] x15: 0000007fc1ea0b58 x14: 00000000ffffffff 
[  400.259344] x13: 0000000000000000 x12: 0000007fc1ea0bb8 
[  400.259353] x11: 0000000000000000 x10: ffffff80ebe9b848 
[  400.259362] x9 : 0000000000000018 x8 : ffffff80ebe9b000 
[  400.259371] x7 : ffffffdb80000000 x6 : ffffffe51f341c08 
[  400.259380] x5 : ffffffe51f341c08 x4 : 0000000000000000 
[  400.259391] x3 : 0000000000000140 x2 : 00000000000000b8 
[  400.259409] x1 : ffffffe551910000 x0 : fffffffffffffffe 
[  400.259420] 
[  400.259420] PC: 0xffffff80e9b9cb84:
[  400.259426] cb84  b4000061 aa1303e0 d63f0020 b40011b4 b9404320 375811a0 aa1703e0 97ed6d39
[  400.259456] cba4  910203a0 52800021 92f00002 97ed3cda aa1703e0 94275ce6 f9400b80 f9400400
[  400.259482] cbc4  f9400000 37000f60 aa1903e0 97ffeadc 35000f40 f9410e60 b4000060 b941e800
[  400.259509] cbe4  34000ec0 b9413660 36000b00 b4fffc74 f9414276 91400ac4 910ac09a aa1a03e0
[  400.259540] 
[  400.259540] LR: 0xffffff80e9b9cac0:
[  400.259546] cac0  b9413c02 f9004bb5 f9003fa1 37400262 91036277 9108c27b aa1703e0 f000575a
[  400.259577] cae0  aa1803f5 94275d1b aa1303e0 d538411c 97fffeda aa1b03e0 910203a1 97ed3b74
[  400.259603] cb00  b0005500 91302000 f9003ba0 9108c340 f90037a0 1400002a f9401721 f9400c22
[  400.259629] cb20  90ffffe1 9139c021 eb01005f 54fffd20 97fff30a 93407c1a b4fffcda 140000b4
[  400.259657] 
[  400.259657] SP: 0xffffffe551913c30:
[  400.259663] 3c30  e9b9cb00 ffffff80 51913c70 ffffffe5 e9b9cbc4 ffffff80 60400145 00000000
[  400.259691] 3c50  1f344000 ffffffe5 00000008 00000000 00000000 00000080 e9b9cae8 ffffff80
[  400.259718] 3c70  51913d20 ffffffe5 e9b98ddc ffffff80 1f344000 ffffffe5 00000000 00000000
[  400.259757] 3c90  00000008 00000000 00000008 00000000 dcdda200 ffffffe5 69230000 00000070
[  400.259782] 
[  400.259788] Process cve-2019-2215 (pid: 6877, stack limit = 0xffffffe551910028)
[  400.259794] Call trace:
[  400.259803] Exception stack(0xffffffe551913a80 to 0xffffffe551913bb0)
[  400.259812] 3a80: ffffffe51f344000 0000008000000000 0000000082b33000 ffffff80e9b9cbc4
[  400.259821] 3aa0: 0000000060400145 ffffffe5f4005000 ffffffe551913ad0 ffffff80ea460dcc
[  400.259829] 3ac0: ffffffe551913b10 ffffff80e97ba680 0000000000000000 ffffffe5f9403c00
[  400.259837] 3ae0: ffffffe551910000 0000000000000000 ffffffbe57b3d700 000000000004cbc2
[  400.259845] 3b00: ffffffe551910000 0000000000000000 ffffffe551913c30 ffffff80e97ba950
[  400.259852] 3b20: ffffffbe57b3d700 ffffffe5ecf5d800 ffffffe551910000 953d5989c78ca9ec
[  400.259859] Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 00000022
[  400.259863] pgd = ffffffe5619b1000
[  400.259867] [00000022] *pgd=00000000e409f003, *pud=00000000e409f003[  400.259872] 3b40: fffffffffffffffe ffffffe551910000 00000000000000b8 0000000000000140
[  400.259877] 3b60: 0000000000000000 ffffffe51f341c08 ffffffe51f341c08 ffffffdb80000000
[  400.259882] 3b80: ffffff80ebe9b000 0000000000000018 ffffff80ebe9b848 0000000000000000
[  400.259886] 3ba0: 0000007fc1ea0bb8 0000000000000000
[  400.259895] [<ffffff80e9b9cbc4>] n_tty_write+0x168/0x3e8
[  400.259901] [<ffffff80e9b98ddc>] tty_write+0x1d4/0x268
[  400.259913] [<ffffff80e97cbf30>] __vfs_write+0x38/0xfc
[  400.259920] [<ffffff80e97cc848>] vfs_write+0xac/0x16c
[  400.259926] [<ffffff80e97cd1ec>] SyS_write+0x54/0xa4
[  400.259936] [<ffffff80e9683170>] el0_svc_naked+0x24/0x28
[  400.259942] Code: aa1703e0 94275ce6 f9400b80 f9400400 (f9400000)
```

I tried changing `0xfffffffffffffffe` to something lower but that didn't work. I also looked at `n_tty_write`.

It looks like the crash comes from something in this loop: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.78/source/drivers/tty/n_tty.c#L2352

The `n_tty_write+0x168` corresponds to this instruction(`859cbc4` asm left, C line `45` from Ghidra right) [image]

I tried digging further but it's taking a huge amount of time, I'd really appreciate any tips from more experienced people.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that you need to recheck your task_struct and thread_info offsets and the offset you're writing the addr_limit to is wrong.

I think that the panic happens in `if (signal_pending(current)) {` in original source.

Here is what you can do for checking the offsets:

1. download the corresponding kernel source, compile it and use [pahole](https://lwn.net/Articles/206805/) ([git](https://github.com/acmel/dwarves), [example usage](https://groups.google.com/g/vmitools/c/zjp0YQyiEnE?pli=1)) for relevant structures. This will show you the exact offset of addr_limit that you need.
2. If you have /proc/config.gz on your phone, you can pull it, unpack it and see all config constants used for building the kernel. This can help you to check offsets manually.